# Call a function of an external static class from a string, in a static class

Tags: c#, mysql

The title it's a bit confusing but let me clear it up.

I'm tring to build a Speech recognition system and I want to have the functions in a string in the MySQL database:

```
`function` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, //function executed (Ex: "Commands.demoFunction();")
```

So, when I get the function from the MySQL database i have to execute it, 
therefore i have to parse it from a string to a "callable" function, like:

```
Commands.demoFunction();
```

At this point you will have noticed that the function is in a Static class called Commands which is the real problem

also, the call to Commands.demoFunction() it has to be done from a Static class as well.

To sum it up I would like to do something like:
`{"Commands.demoFunction();"}`or `{"Commands.demoFunction"}();`
and make this execute the function.

Comment: What should happen if the string contains `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()` or `Directory.Delete("C:\\Windows")`?

Comment: Maybe you can try on different way. You can factory pattern and base on result from query resolve appropriate type which handle your request? In that case you don't need to pass functions you need to pass only commands and you can control better.

Comment: So, something like based on the result from the database, make a switch that leads to the propper function?

Comment: @Neku80 Something like `switch`, but if you want to make more robust solution I am recommending factory pattern.

Comment: @kat1330 You mean to dedicate an entire class to that switch am I right? and then, from there call the function of the Command class? like:

Comment: case "openNav" : Command.OpenNav(); break;

Comment: @Neku80 Yes, entire class. Example you can store Key/Value pairs in database. By Key you can resolve class and by Value you can resolve method in class. Let say that you have: speak/loud pair. Factory will resolve class `Speak` and class itself will resolves method `Loud()`. Not sure about your system, but this is first thing on my mind. This approach is testable and easy for extension.

Comment: @kat1330 I'll follow your recomentations, thank you very much